# What is the order of efficiency of an Adjacency list

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Is it `O(n+m)` or `O(nm)`? To construct it be `O(nm)` and if we wanted to search, add, or delete a value it will be `O(n+m)`, right? Is there anything else that would be important to consider?

Also to convert a matrix into a list it takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) and to turn a list into a matrix it is only `O(nm)` correct?

Comment: No. You're basically wrong all along ;) You should read your lecture notes again or google it, because it looks like you didn't understand how it works at all. Or try to explain why you think these are the correct complexities, and we'll tell you where you're wrong and why.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question, how is your adjacency list implemented `edges[i].from`, `edges[i].to` (ordered/not) or is it an array with `edges[from]=to` ?

Comment: "only" `O(nm)` could also mean `O(n^3)` (if m = `O(n^2)`)

Comment: In response to Tomer, I am thinking about both actually, and I am trying to think of the tree as an array, and then, think of an array, similar to a priority que like structure...or an array with a set of linked lists...something along those lines if that is clear. 

So I was looking it over, to convert an adjacency matrix to an array, would it be O(n^2) and vice versa would be O(nm).

To insert into a matrix will probably be O(1) and a list would be O(n).

An adjacency matrix probably takes O(n^2) space and adjacency list will take O(n+m) space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The cost to build an adjacency list is O(m) from zero (because we can add any edge in O(1)) and O(n²) from an adjacency matrix (because we have to check every cell of the matrix).
- Adding an edge u-v is O(1) because we can append an entry v to the end of the adjacency list of vertex u
- Removing an edge u-v takes O(n) operations because we have to scan the adjacency list of vertex u in order to find the entry for v before we can remove it.
- Finding if there is an edge u-v also takes O(n) steps because we must scan the adjacency list of vertex u and check if there is an entry for v

Remotion and search can me improved to O(logN) or average O(1) using a BST or hashing instead of a linked list to store the adjacencies, but most graph algorithms require us to scan the whole adjacency list of a vertex instead of checking individual entries, so we can usually work well with linked lists.

We can convert an adjacency list to an adjacency matrix in O(m), assuming the matrix is initially filled with zeroes. All we have to do is scan the adjacency list of every vertex, and for each edge U-V with weight W we can do matrix[U][V] = W (or matrix[U][V] = 1 if the graph is not weighted). Since we are looking to each edge exactly once (or twice if the graph is not directed), the complexity os O(m).

Comment: I think that your runtimes of O(m) are assuming that n = O(m). In a graph with vastly more nodes than edges, the cost of simply initializing the adjacency list might dwarf the time spent adding edges.

Comment: Yeah, i'm assuming m >= n. Even though its possible, graphs with less edges than vertices are quite unusual (in my experience, at least)

Answer (score 0):

i think that when you convert the list to the matrix you go:

```
for each vertex `O(n)`
    for each neighbour `O(n)`
```

and that's why its also O(n^2).

if m>n, one vertex cannot have all m neighbors, and that's why you avoid `O(n^3)`

exemple:

`a: b, c, d`

`b: a, c, d`

`c: a, b, d`

`d: a, b, c`

full graph: `O(n^2)` list size. although n = 4 and m = 6, the size is 4x4 and not 4x6.

(m = (4 * (4-1))/2 = 6 = `O(n^2)` --full graph formula)

Comment: Yes but, in general, it is just O(m). m does not have to be O(n^2), although it is often the case in practical applications.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it well.

Comment: Why would it be O(m)? Because we don't need to repeats?

Comment: @Lucas explains that in his answer. The inner loop here is quite misleading, because in reality the total time spent in it is the sum of the degrees of all nodes, which is 2m. You add the cost of going through all nodes and you get O(n+m), which is the academic answer. But in general, as m dominates n, we just write O(m).

Comment: right! although m is not necessarily dominates n... i would agree on `O(n+m)`, because after all, all the right parts together, sums to 2m.